random characters appear on keyboard pressing in PyDroid terminal
I'm using LineageOS 20 GSI, installed over Android12 stock.
Basically, in PyDroid terminal half of the letters of the keyboard appear as "^@". I tried different versions it happens everytime. Something related to character encoding may be, i tried to remove " default to UTF8" ,but no success.
Do you have any idea what could be the reason?
